# Error: Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in php code

Tags: php

I have a problem in my php code. does anyone know how to fix this? Help me please!
Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in `C:\xampp\htdocs\stock\dashboard.php on line 15`

Code:

```
$totalRevenue = "";
while ($orderResult = $orderQuery->fetch_assoc()) {
    $totalRevenue += $orderResult['paid'];
}
```

Comment: Set `$totalRevenue` to 0, not an empty string, when you declare it.

Comment: Change $totalRevenue = ""; to $totalRevenue = 0;

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize $totalRevenue to 0, not an empty string